# how to html entity decode in controller method in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

how to html entity decode in controller method in **laravel 5.2** , i have been trying this with php code  , but till no effect.

I have use e() to encode html , bu to decode i didn't find any method in **laravel 5.2** so i used customem code in the controller method

```
html_entity_decode($user_master_dbdta->banner_description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

But still all efforts went in vein . I need guide on this . As because i am sending this data in json format to a view  where rendered using angular.